# Why cv2.putText flip text vertically when bottomLeftOrigin sets to True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Consider a simple example of adding text to image with `cv2` where bottomLeftOrigin sets as default as False:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image.png')
xy = (0, 200)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fontScale = 1
color = (0, 255, 0)
thickness = 2
image = cv2.putText(image, 'OpenCV', xy, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA, False)
cv2.imwrite("frame1.png", image)
```

for given example I get output image as expected:

[image: EXPECTED]

but if I change it to True I get unexpected image where text is flipped vertically and locates on not expected coordinates:

```
...
xy = (0, 0)
image = cv2.putText(image, 'OpenCV', xy, font, fontScale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA, True)
...
```

[image: UNEXPECTED]

I am expecting an image on which the text not inversed and locates in bottom left corner.

Comment: Read the documentation: bottomLeftOrigin When true, the image data origin is at the bottom-left corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576 in your memory, data origin is top left

Comment: yes, it's a strange flag. likely "historical", or for compatibility with some flavors of BMP, if I had to speculate. yes, that makes it useless if you wanted to draw text given a "baseline". you'd have to use another API to get the text's bounds first, and then putText with an origin based on these values.

Comment: You can use cv2.getTextSize as a helper to calculate the wanted position: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82